# Rest Assured Java : How to obtain id in the response not in json format

Tags: testing, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to obtain the response of an endpoint that returns a number but not in json format, only a number returns. When I try to do response.prettyprint() I didnt see nothing in the console. Is there any way to obtain that number in the response? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print that information, just use:

```
Response res = ...
res.print();
```

To get Infor, save Response as `String` then convert type to `int`

```
String res = ...asString();
int number = Integer.valueOf(res);
```